# Twitter Paid Premium API search returns "Twitter Request Error 422"

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I’m collecting tweets for research with python and package “TwitterAPI”. It worked well yesterday, but not today. I don’t know where I changed wrongfully today.

```
tweets = api.request('tweets/search/30day/:covidsearch', {'query' : 'gook','fromDate': '202003090000','toDate': '202003100000'}) 
for t in tweets:
    print (t['text'])
```

and it returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TwitterRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-cf0d843438dd> in <module>
----> 1 for t in tweets:
      2     print (t['text'])

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py in __iter__(self)
    218         :raises: TwitterConnectionError, TwitterRequestError
    219         """
--> 220         return self.get_iterator()
    221 
    222     def get_quota(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py in get_iterator(self)
    205         """
    206         if self.response.status_code != 200:
--> 207             raise TwitterRequestError(self.response.status_code)
    208 
    209         if self.stream:

TwitterRequestError: Twitter request failed (422)
```

anybody knows why? HELP!

Comment: The 422 error code means it understands the content type of the request entity, but was unable to process the contained instructions.

Comment: I think your problem might be the 'print (t['text'])' function.